# map value with arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

```
if (rs != null) {

    while (rs.next()) {
        rb = new ResponseBean();

        rb.setQuestionOrderNo(rs.getInt(1));

        rb.setResponseLabel(rs.getString(2));

        rb.setTaskName(rs.getString(3));

        rb.setResponder(rs.getString(4));

        rb.setSequenceId(rs.getInt(5));

        checkBoxResponses.add(rb);
    }
}
```

The output for this is : 
    rs1=10

```
rs2=Sam

rs3=Manyu

rs4=manyu

rs5=13621

rs1=10

rs2=Sam
--------------------------
rs3=Manyu

rs4=manyu

rs5=13623
------------------------------------
rs1=10

rs2=Sam US
--------------------------------
rs3=Manyu

rs4=manyu

rs5=13623
-------------------------------------------
rs1=10

rs2=Sam India

rs3=Manyu

rs4=manyu

rs5=13624
```

I want to map value of r5=13623 with value of r2=Sam, Sam US.
Please suggest me how to proceed with this to get the out put as

```
<13621,Sam>

<13623,(Sam, Sam US)>

<13624, Sam India>
```

Comment: better you should have done mapping at SQL level only.

Comment: It's not a question but code only. Reframe this question else it would be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a map to do this:-

```
HashMap<Integer, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>(); //Create the Map
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Map<Integer, List<String>>` instead?

Comment: but how to map particular integer with particular string....

Comment: in the `while` loop, for every `r5` value, check if an entry exists, in the map. If an entry does exist, then add your `r2` to the existing list, if not create a new list, add `r2` to it and put that in the map, with your `r5`.

Comment: @R.J Thanks...for the solution..!!!

Comment: Happy to help:) Do accept the answer if it helped you!